# Movie about a family living on a floating island that had ships

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

So my husband is trying to find a movie he watched as a kid. He said it’s a live action movie about a family that lived on a floating island and they didn’t have powers. But they would use their ships to come help when disaster struck. Does this ring any bells? It’s not Sky High or Zoom or Up Up and Away

He thinks the island was floating.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year would your husband have watched this? Also, did he see it in a movie theatre, on TV, online, or on home media?

Comment: Just to  be sure, is the island floating in the air (like Laputa), or is it floating in the sea?

Comment: Can you clarify if "ships" means things that float on water or something else, like spacecraft or aircraft?

Answer (score 13):

Sounds like [Thunderbirds (2004)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_(2004_film))

> The Tracy family, led by former astronaut Jeff Tracy, operate International Rescue (IR), a secret organization that aids those in need during disasters using technologically advanced machines called Thunderbirds, operating out of Tracy Island in the South Pacific.

based upon a [1960's TV show.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_(TV_series))   The film was live action. The TV show was made with models and puppets.

The vessels included advanced aeroplanes, cars,  a space station, a rocket ship and a submarine.

It was a real island. Probably a Pacific archipelago. It didn't float.

Comment: Wow, that's even cheesier than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Is it Waterworld with Kevin Costner?

Or is it Nim's Island?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When answering story-ID questions though, you should really only submit one story per answer (unless the question is about a series). It's also good to explain why you think a given story might be the one the OP was looking for, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.